# PyQtGraph: how to catch plot range changes?

Tags: pyqt, pyqtgraph

I have a PyQtGraph plot, that can be zoomed or panned. It changes its ranges. Cannot I somehow get known, when a plot changes its ranges?

Answer (score 3):

Connect your chosen method (slot) to the `PlotItem.sigRangeChanged` signal (see http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotitem.html )